# How to print 02-Jun-2019 in bash

Tags: bash

How to print `dd-mmm-yyyy` in bash (e.g 02-Jun-2019)

```
today=$(date +%d-%m-%Y -d "yesterday")
```

which doesn't give the desired result

I expected to get `02-Jun-2019` but output is `02-06-2019`

Comment: The list of all the format codes is in `man strftime`.

Comment: Have a look at `man date`. All you want to know can be found in there.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
date -d "yesterday" '+%d-%b-%Y'
```

Gives you yesterday's date in the format you desire:

```
02-Jun-2019
```

If you want it to be `May`, then you can do:

```
date -d "yesterday -1 month" '+%d-%b-%Y'
```

Gives you:

```
02-May-2019
```